# Can Umbraco pass a model to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I am quite new to this Umbraco MVC.
I need to pass some data bound to a model to my partial view from the GET action method.

This simply is not working in a regular MVC way.

```
[httpget] 
public ActionResult Membership()
    {
        SupplierMembershipInfoModel mm = new SupplierMembershipInfoModel();
        mm.ProductPackage = "sssssssss";


        ViewBag.status = Request.QueryString["status"];

        return PartialView("MembershipPartial", mm);
}
```

my view:

```
@model Umbraco.Web.Models.SupplierMembershipInfoModel

some html.....
<td>@Model.ProductPackage</td>
```

I don't get data here...and the debug never hits the action. But it hits any POST action method.
I know i am doing something wrong...but just don't know what the mistake is??
Any ideas??

Comment: You might want to check out this topic: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/45841-Simple-Example-of-SurfaceController- Ps. You should never use a namespace in your own project that starts with Umbraco, what is the core suddenly starts shipping with a SupplierMembershipInfoModel in the same namespace?

Comment: Hi.Thanks. I tried as it described in the link but got some error. The error says "No route in the route table matches the supplied values."

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastiaan points out, the best place to start is the Umbraco community site. There is documentation specific to your issue here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/child-actions

In a nutshell, you want to display a child action on your page and Umbraco uses SurfaceControllers for this. A SurfaceController is simply a Controller that inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController`. This provides you Controller with access to the Umbraco context - see here (http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/surface-controllers).

Either way, you should read the whole documentation section on templating as it will give you a lot of insight into how Umbraco MVC is managed.